# elemination of similar values in JSON array

Tags: javascript

I want to display array values which not similar in both arrays presently using Angular 7.

```
 json1 = {
     "status": "success",
     "data": {
         "priority": [
             "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
         ]
     }
 }
 res = {
     "status": "success",
     "data": {
         "priority": ["1", "2"]
     }
 }

 if (this.res.status == 'success') {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(this.res))
     this.prioritydata = [];
     for (let i in this.res.data.priority) {
         for (let j in this.json1.data.priority) {
             if (this.res.data.priority[i] == this.json1.data.priority[j]) {
                 this.prioritydata.push(this.json1.data.priority[j]);
                 console.log("prioritydatasuccess - " + JSON.stringify(this.prioritydata))
             }
         }
     }
 }

 exp answer - ["3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` like that

```
let result = json1.data.priority.filter(value => json1.data.priority.indexOf(value) === -1);
```